# Can't override Checkout in Magento 1.7.0.2

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7, overriding, checkout

I can't seem to override the Checkout controller in **Magento**.
I copied the folder in the `app/code/local/Checkout` but it doesn't seem to work.

Other people who just copy pasted the folder seem to get it right.
Is there something that needs to be done?

Answer (score 1):

This is not the recommended way to extend a controller. I am going to assume you are to extend the Checkout OnepageController.

The correct way of doing this would be.

1.) Identify the correct module or create a new module for this.

app/code/local/Mel/Gallosa (remember to activate the module in app/etc/modules)

Add files etc/config.xml and controllers/OnepageController.php

The content of your files will be

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <Mel_Gallosa>
          <version>0.1.0</version>
        </Mel_Gallosa>
    </modules>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <checkout>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <modules>
                        <Mel_Gallosa before="Mage_Checkout">Mel_Gallosa</Mel_Gallosa>
                    </modules>
                </args>
            </checkout>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

Then your new controller file

```
<?php
require_once 'Mage/Checkout/controllers/OnepageController.php';
class Mel_Gallosa_OnepageController extends Mage_Checkout_OnepageController
{
    /*you can now overide any method here. Remember that you want to extend code in an Object Orientated fashion. Call the parent functions when appropriate and at the right time. Only replace methods that you are trying to overwrite. There is no need to dump all methods here. */

  //here is an example

  public function indexAction()
  {
      Mage::log('we have now overwritten the index action',null,'mel.log');

      parent::indexAction(); /* this means that if there are any core updates you will get them too :) */
  }
}
```

And that's it. My advice is not do simply copy folders over. Think clearly about what you are trying to do and make sure you dont do something that "could shoot you in the foot" later. Keep OO in-tact!